# Different answers for File Exists Function

Tags: .net

Consider the following code example:

```
Dim oFile = GetFileInfoAsync()       ' Some function returning a FileInfo object

Dim b1 = oFile.Exists()              ' Return False
Dim b2 = File.Exists(oFile.FullName) ' Return True
```

Can anyone explain please?
JP

Comment: Is this _precisely_ what your actual code looks like? I ask as there's a slight difference between `FileInfo.Exists` and `File.Exists`, in that `FileInfo` caches the result the first time it's called.

Comment: Hi James
The only difference is the GetFileInfoAsync(). I got a more complex Async Function calling Azure to download a file and return it as a File Info.

Comment: @JPScerri: If you call `oFile.Refresh()` before `Exists` you get `true` too?

Comment: Right, so it could well have built up information about the file, including whether it currently exists on disk or not, long before the download has even started.  As Tim says, asking it to manually refresh it's internal state may bring them into alignment.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just refreshed the sate of the FileInfo object in my async class just before returning it and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by me and James: call [`Refresh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh?view=net-7.0) before you return the `FileInfo` object, then all properties like `Exists` have the current state. Otherwise the information may be outdated.